# using this percentage function in Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, function, percentage

Hi I have this function I found

```
function valueToPercent($value:Number, $min:Number, $max:Number):Number {
var myPercent:Number;
var difference:Number = $max - $min;
myPercent = (($value - $min) / difference);
return myPercent;
}
```

How would I define those variables and get a result? I need to output various percentages which will become variables, which will then power a pie chart...

This didn't work, but I've obviously done it wrong

```
function valueToPercent($value:Number, $min:Number, $max:Number):Number {
var myPercent:Number;
var difference:Number = $max - $min;
myPercent = (($value - $min) / difference);
return myPercent;
}

valueToPercent(45, 0, 345);

Trace(valueToPercent);
```

Thanks!

Comment: What doesn't work ? What did you expect ? Obviously this function isn't gonna draw you a pie chart, it just gives a number from to 0 to 1 based on min and max.

Comment: Haha yes I know that. I've basically forgotten all my flash skills. I just want to output some numbers using that formula above, but can't remember the correct way to do so. 
I want to input the variables VALUE, MIN and MAX, and it to give me a percentage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. When a method returns a value, you can asign it to a variable of type that it returns

```
var percentage:Number = valueToPercent(45, 0, 345);
trace(percentage);
```

and/or

```
trace(valueToPercent(45, 0, 345));
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I can figure the rest out from here! nice one